# What access does an anonymous function have in Javascript (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the text from the response body to a request into a global variable.

```
var Request = require('request');

var result = "Not set";                

var foodrequest = Request({ uri: url }, function (error, response, body) {
            result = body;
});

console.log(result);
```

the "result" variable however is not set correctly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: They have the same access any other function has. Scope (access) isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the callback for `Request` is called asynchronously, while whatever is found after the invokation of the function named `Request` is executed (let me say) synchronously.
That means that the `console.log` statement has no chance to be executed after the callback.
So, when you reach the `console.log` statement, the above mentioned function has not been invoked yet.